# Changing values of elements using SASS based on HTML classes

Tags: html, css, sass

Assume I have two html pages in the same website, as follows:

*This is the first page*

```css
.theme1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: green;
}

p.special {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body class="theme1">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="special">Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
</body>
```

*And this is the second page*

```css
.theme2 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: pink;
}

h2 {
  color: darkblue;
}

p.special {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body class="theme2">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="special">Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
</body>
```

As you notice, the pages have exactly the same HTML, except for the fact that the first page has class `theme1` and the second page has class `theme2`. CSS is different in both (in reality, I will have different HTML structure, but similar CSS structure).

I would like to create a **.scss** file, and use SASS to detect the class in `body`, and choose the right theme values based on the class. How do I do that? I thought of using functions, but I am not sure how to let SASS detect that the page has `theme1` or `theme2` in the `body` element.

My idea was to do something like this in the **.scss** file:

```
$theme1: (
    body-bg-color: black,
    body-font-color: white,
    h2-font-color: green,
    p-special-font-color: orange
);

$theme2: (
    body-bg-color: darkgray,
    body-font-color: silver,
    h2-font-color: darkblue,
    p-special-font-color: yellow
);

@function getBackgroundColorForBody () {

    // DETECT THEME
    $theme-name = <detected class of body>; // This is not correct, just an idea

    $bg-color = map-get($theme-name 'body-bg-color');
    @return $bg-color;
}

body {
    background-color: @getBackgroundColorForBody();
}
```

I am new to SASS, so I am not sure how I can do this. Apologies about the simple quesiton.

Comment: SASS/SCSS cannot determine the class of an HTML element dynamically. SCSS/SASS is *compiled* to CSS and the CSS is what is read by the browser. You need to setup different styles based on the `body.theme1` and `body.theme2`.

Comment: @disinfor - Thanks. But can you elaborate what you mean by setting up a `:root` var in HTML?

Comment: I edited the comment, since `:root` var won't help you either. The best way to think about SCSS/SASS, is it's a very helpful preprocessor to make writing complex (and simple) CSS easier with functions, mixins, etc. At the end, it's always compiled to plain CSS and the browser reads the CSS.

Comment: @disinfor is right - there's really no need to detect the class since you'll have to define its properties anyway.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I now understand. I was thinking wrong altogether. Maybe I should delete the question?

Comment: This is trivial using custom CSS properties, but if you can't, you'd have to create two stylesheets based on their 'parent' theme, I've done it before following [this](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1) guide and it works well.

Comment: @eMontielG - Thanks so much. This is exactly what I am looking for.